# Read Random Access File in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb6, vb6-migration, randomaccessfile

Does anyone know if it is possible to read random access files in C#?

I am trying to replicate the following function (from an old VB6 application) in C# -

```
Open File For Random Shared As #100 Len = Len(Record)
    Get #100, DM, Record
Close #100

Public DM As Long
Public Record As DMrecord

Public Type DMrecord
column1 As Long
column2 As Integer
column3 As Integer
column4 As Integer
column5 As String * 4
End Type
```

**EDIT -**

I have now tried using the VisualBasic DLL as suggested below and receive the following error on the FileGetObject line -

"The best overloaded method match for Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.FileGetObject(int, ref object, long) has some invalid argument"

The code I am using is -

```
        public class Record 
    {
        public int DMtype;
        public long ecn;


        public Record(int DMtype, long ecn) 
        {
            this.DMtype = DMtype;
            this.ecn = ecn;
        }

        public Record()
        {
        }
    }


string fileName = @"C:\RandomAccess.dat";
        string returnString = string.Empty;
        int row = 1;
        int maxRow = 1000;

        Record aFileRecord = new Record();

        FileSystem.FileOpen(1, fileName, OpenMode.Random, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.LockRead);

        while (row < maxRow)
        {
            //Get record 2 1st.>>
            FileSystem.FileGetObject(1, aFileRecord, row);
            returnString += aFileRecord.DMtype.ToString() + "$" + aFileRecord.ecn.ToString();
            row++;
        }

        FileSystem.FileClose(1);
```

I have tried setting 'Record' as both a struct and a class and get the same error.

**EDIT 22/08/13** - I never did get to the bottom of this, ended up exporting the random access data to comma seperated text files in VB6, then consuming the files in SSIS.

Comment: You will have to interpret the data yourself using BinaryReader. [See here to get started](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429829/read-variable-sized-string-from-binary-file-vb6-vs-c) Long you can read with `BinaryReader.ReadInt64()`, Integer with `BinaryReader.ReadInt32()`, and the strings you will have to read one at a time. Read them as described in the link I gave.

Comment: note: vb6 Long was actually int32

Comment: Oops, so I should have said "Long you can read with `BinaryReader.ReadInt32()`"

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/q/265639/17776

Comment: Just a guess, `object aFileRecord = new Record()` and `FileSystem.FileGetObject(1, ref aFileRecord, row)`

Answer (score 1):

Just add a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` and use [`FileSystem.FileOpen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.fileopen.aspx) specifying `Random` open mode, and the [`FileSystem.FileGetObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.filegetobject.aspx) method. This behaves the same as the `Open` statement and `Get` keyword in VB6.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll have a look into the VisualBasic.dll now.

Comment: Hmm, can't quite get this working. The FileSystem.FileGetObject(1, aFileRecord, 1) line is throwing an error when I try to pass in a new instance of a struct (aFileRecord in the line above). Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Just to add, the error is - "The best overloaded method match for Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileSystem.FileGetObject(int, ref object, long) has some invalid arguments"

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't like structs. You could try using a class instead?? (Disclaimer - I'm recommending these techniques based on the documentation, and haven't actually used them myself.)

Comment: I have tried both a class and a struct, both receiving the same error, see the question for an edit containing updated code.

Comment: @user1948635 You have forgotten to put *ref aFileRecord*. The method expects a reference to an object there, not the object itself.